# Stored procedure not working as i want

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a stored procedure like this

```
BEGIN
SELECT concat(stationsNavn,' ',city,' ',adresse,' ',postnummer)as navn,id
from AdresseListeBioAnlæg order by stationsNavn,city
inner join bioAlarmer on AdresseListeBioAnlæg.id = bioAlarmer.station;
end
```

With "as navn,id" i can create it, but i dont get anything, and with "order by stationsNavn,city" i get an error on create. It works fine without any of them like this.

```
BEGIN
SELECT concat(stationsNavn,' ',city,' ',adresse,' ',postnummer)
from AdresseListeBioAnlæg 
inner join bioAlarmer on AdresseListeBioAnlæg.id = bioAlarmer.station;
end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your order by is in the wrong place.  as navn,id ain't going to work unless you have a column called id.

Answer (score 0):

try this out, I moved the `order by` and did it by `navn` and `id`

```
BEGIN
SELECT concat(stationsNavn,' ',city,' ',adresse,' ',postnummer)as navn,id
from AdresseListeBioAnlæg
inner join bioAlarmer on AdresseListeBioAnlæg.id = bioAlarmer.station
order by navn, id
end
```